# Cross-platform method to obtain list of FreeType font paths in C

Tags: c, windows, unix, path, freetype

I've written a simple C wrapper for SDL_ttf which in turn uses FreeType 1.2.

Although I use my own (non-system) fonts for most applications, it would be useful to have access to more fonts available on the system.

Is there any method or perhaps library on its own which can provide me with a list of font paths to glob for files (or a similar mechanism) ? At this time I'm doing something  heretical like having a hard-coded list of paths to try - which often fails as I don't know which platform I'm running on.

Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks for any responders.

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution for this problem? I've been looking all over trying to find this exact thing.

Comment: Unfortunately not. What I'm currently doing is to include a free set of fonts with my software, avoiding the problem altogether. This doesn't help me finding any system fonts though. If you find something, please keep me informed!

Answer (score 1):

Crossplatform solution I don't know. You use SDL, check it docs.

For Windows  you can read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162615%28v=vs.85%29.aspx (Enumerating the Installed Fonts).

Also check [How to get a list of installed True Type Fonts on Linux using C or C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203257/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-true-type-fonts-on-linux-using-c-or-c)

Comment: SDL_ttf (not actually a part of SDL) does not have any functionality for this. Thanks for the links!

Answer (score 0):

Pygame uses SDL2 and gets a list of system fonts in a cross-platform way. If you look at the Pygame source code, you might get an idea of how to do it, specifically in sysfont.py. You can see that for Unix, fc-list command is run as a subprocess.